# how to know which button called view controller in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have 3 view controllers. view1, view2, view3 View1 & view2 has add button both button called same view controller view3. how do you know which button called view 3

plz let me know how to know which button called view3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `tag` property of the Add Buttons from the *view1* and *view2* to say **1** and **2** respectively.

```
btnInView1.tag = 1;   //in view1.
btnInView2.tag = 2;   //in view2.
```

What you have to do is to create property for some `int` variable say `tagNo` in *view3*.

```
@property (nonatomic) int tagNo;     //in view3.
```

You have to set the `tagNo` to the `tag` value of Add Button before changing to *view3*.

```
ViewController3 *view3 = [[ViewController3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController3" bundle:nil];
view3.tagNo = btnInView1.tag    //in view1.
//view3.tagNo = btnInView2.tag  //in view2.
```

Now, in  *view3*, you just have to check the value of `tagNo`. 
If it's **1** that means *view3* is loaded from *view1* else from *view2* or you can say if it's **1** that means *view3* is loaded by Add Button inside *view1* else by  Add Button inside *view2*.

```
if (self.tagNo == 1)
{
    NSLog("view3 is loaded by Add Button inside view1.");
}
else if (self.tagNo == 2)
{
    NSLog("view3 is loaded by Add Button inside view2.");
}
else
{
    NSLog("It will never reach here.");
}
```

Comment: can you explain how to do it?

Comment: @nidhu : Is that fine ?

Answer (score 2):

create a property and synthesize it on your view controller 3 like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ComingForm;
```

Now on your button touched event on your viewcontroller #1 & #2 while you create your object of viewcontroller 3 to push just set "ComingForm" value. like

```
viewcontroller3 *__viewcontroller3=[[viewcontroller3 alloc] init];
[__viewcontroller3 setComingForm: @"View1"];
```

Now you can easly got from which viewcontroller you are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

In first view .h file

```
@property (nonatomic)int btncTag;
```

In first view .m file

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"btnc"])
    {
        btncTag =1;
        ButtonfinalViewController *btnf = segue.destinationViewController;
        btnf.Tag = btncTag;
    }
}
```

In second view .h file

```
@property (nonatomic)int btnpTag;
```

In second view .m file

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pbtn"])
    {
        btnpTag = 2;
        ButtonfinalViewController *btnf = segue.destinationViewController;
        btnf.Tag = btnpTag;

    }
}
```

in Third view .h

```
@property (nonatomic)int Tag;
```

in Third view .m

```
- (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender
{
    ButtonCViewController *btnc = [[ButtonCViewController alloc]init];
    btnc.btncTag = Tag;
    ButtonPViewController *btnp = [[ButtonPViewController alloc]init];
    btnp.btnpTag =Tag;

    if (Tag == 1)
    {
        UIStoryboard *menuViewStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        ButtonCViewController *btnc = [menuViewStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BtnCView"];
        [self presentViewController:btnc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    if (Tag == 2)
    {
        UIStoryboard *menuViewStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
       ButtonPViewController *btnp = [menuViewStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BtnPView"];
        [self presentViewController:btnp animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```